# How can you generate PDF From GSP Page in Grails?

Tags: grails

I want to export the information on my gsp page to pdf.

How can I do that. Can you share some example.
Please check the image attached.
[image: Need to export the table in gsp to pdf.]

Comment: There are quite a few other answers here on that topic; can you give any more info on why they're not working for you?  Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156614/grails-generating-pdf-from-gsp?rq=1

Comment: @Daniel I need an In depth explanation, the answer over here is just an overview and the link shared on the green tick answer doesn't lead me any where with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Grails Rendering plugin for generating PDFs from Grails.  Easy to use and generates from a GSP uses iText under the covers.

https://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/rendering

Here is how it is called and templates start with a underscore:

```
response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="Case_Summary_'+selectedCase+'.pdf"')

renderPdf(template: "print", model: [selectedCase: selectedCase, locationList: locationList])
```

Here is the top of the GSP with some iText settings:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Case ${selectedCase} Summary</title>
    <style  type="text/css">
    @page {
        size: 8.5in 11in;
        margin: 0.25in;
        counter-increment: page;
        @bottom-right { content: "Created <g:formatDate format='MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a' date="${new Date()}"/>"};
        @bottom-left { content: "Page " counter(page);};
    }
    body {
        font-family: 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
        font-size: 9pt;
    }
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [Grails Jasper Plugin](https://puneetbehl.github.io/grails-jasper/docs/index.html) and create a jasper report with the same format as your GSP and then export it to PDF.